# How to define a test stage in Jenkins pipeline which makes use of curl to check if the server is up or not?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using latest Jenkins in my Linux box.

I would like to implement a `Test` stage like below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') { 
            HTTP_CODE = sh (
                        script: 'echo $(curl --write-out \\"%{http_code}\\" --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost/)',
                        returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()
        }
    }
}
```

In this stage, I want to execute a bash script to check whether the web server is up or not. `HTTP_CODE` variable will have the value `200` if everything is fine, and if there is any other value, then it can be treated as error.

How can I implement this logic as a testing stage in my Jenkins pipeline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your pipeline as follow:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') { 
            HTTP_CODE = sh (
                        script: 'echo $(curl --write-out \\"%{http_code}\\" --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost/)',
                        returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()

            if ('200' != HTTP_CODE) {
                currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                error('Test stage failed!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: The 'error' keyword will throw an exception that will mark the build as failed, there is no need to do it manually in the line before.

Comment: Sure, but I use the assignment to send a post execution mail with the execution status.

Comment: Interesting , as usually the status is defined by the post directive option, but i guess this is also a way, but it  means that you need to place that code inside a 'script' block (also for the `if` statement).